# Core isolation limits OpenMP to a single core

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

After investigating a performance issue of a code, I realized that an OpenMP-based parallel code running on [isolated cores](https://manuel.bernhardt.io/posts/2023-11-16-core-pinning/) limits the number of threads to a single core.

This code should unroll the for-loop to N cores (e.g. `$OMP_NUM_THREADS=N`):

```cpp
// g++ -fopenmp -I/usr/include/ -03 test_openmp.cpp -o testomp
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
const float nano = 1000000000;
int main(){
    std::size_t niter = 10000000000;
    auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < niter; i++){
        std::size_t x = sqrt(i);
    }
    auto elapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now() - start);
    std::cout << "Took " << elapsed.count()/nano << " s" << std::endl;
}
```

On my dev system, there are 32 cores; 0-15 are isolated, while 16-31 are not.
Running the code on the isolated cores gives:

```
OMP_NUM_THREADS=4 taskset -c 0-3 ./testomp
Took 5.33671 s
```

On the non-isolated cores

```
OMP_NUM_THREADS=4 taskset -c 16-19 ./testomp 
Took 1.33193 s
```

In addition, `htop` shows one 100% utilized core for the test with the isolated CPUs while the test with the non-isolated CPUs shows 4 CPU cores are 100% utilized.

[image: Running on isolated core(s)]

[image: Running on non-isolated cores]

Is there a way to allow OpenMP to use multiple isolated cores in a parallel for-loop? Using the isolated cores would be essential for performance reasons (avoiding kernel tasks, etc.).

If not, how does OpenMP differentiate between isolated and non-isolated cores?

**EDIT**

I enabled optimization with `-0 3`. Of course, the execution time decreases, but this is not the point (and also not benchmarking). The point is that the code runs on multiple non-isolated cores but only one isolated core. However, on the isolated core, I see four threads running.

I am using the GNU C++ compiler:

```
~$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.2) 9.4.0
```

OpenMP version is 4.5

The CPU and its configuration:

```
~$ lscpu
lscpu
Architecture:                       x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):                     32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:                         Little Endian
Address sizes:                      52 bits physical, 57 bits virtual
CPU(s):                             128
On-line CPU(s) list:                0-63
Off-line CPU(s) list:               64-127
Thread(s) per core:                 1
Core(s) per socket:                 32
Socket(s):                          2
NUMA node(s):                       2
Vendor ID:                          AuthenticAMD
CPU family:                         25
Model:                              17
Model name:                         AMD EPYC 9354 32-Core Processor
Stepping:                           1
Frequency boost:                    enabled
CPU MHz:                            1499.458
CPU max MHz:                        3799.0720
CPU min MHz:                        1500.0000
BogoMIPS:                           6499.69
Virtualization:                     AMD-V
L1d cache:                          2 MiB
L1i cache:                          2 MiB
L2 cache:                           64 MiB
L3 cache:                           512 MiB
NUMA node0 CPU(s):                  0-31
```

Comment: What compiler and OpenMP  do you use ?

Comment: Your loop does not have any visible effect. An optimizing compiler should be able to remove it. Since it obviously did not, then it means you certainly did not enabled optimization. This last point is critical in performance benchmarks. Please enable optimization. Also please provide environment details (including the processor reference -- not just the number of cores). There are many different OpenMP implementations. Besides, what do you mean by "isolated core"?

Comment: Please define "isolated core" and "non-isolated core". I've never come across these concepts

Comment: Benchmarking non-optimized program builds generally does not make any sense.

Comment: @DanielLangr, it is not about benchmarking at all.

Comment: You are trying to measure the runtime of a piece of code. This is called micro-benchmarking. Please look into an existing micro-benchmarking tool like [google/benchmark](https://github.com/google/benchmark) avoid many benchmarking mistakes/issues. It can also be used to avoid some optimizations, see [Preventing Optimization](https://github.com/google/benchmark/blob/main/docs/user_guide.md#preventing-optimization).

Comment: @paleonix, as I already stated, the issue is not related to (micro)-benchmarking; it is related to how OpenMP (or the system) assigns threads to cores under the use of isolated cores!

Comment: Well, assuming that you want to understand how OpenMP behaves in a release build, you will have to take time measurements in a release build. Time measurements in a unoptimized/debug build are just not representative. Therefore people don't trust your measurements and your analysis based on these measurements.

Comment: Ok, I must confess I didn't read all of the super long page you referenced for defining  what an "isolated core" is, but I've seen this : "the domain flag to isolate the cores from SMP balancing and scheduling algorithms". So in essence, you've disabled the OS capability of load-balancing between cores and then you see that the load isn't balanced. Did I get that correctly?

Comment: @Gilles you are right! With the OMP-pragma statement, the load is not balanced. But it is possible to execute threads on different isolated cores using [CPU_SET](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/CPU_SET.3.html) and pthread_set_affinity when using plain C threads. I wonder, if OpenMP can also do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are asking OpenMP to do something that is impossible. It sits at the bottom of the resource allocation hierarchy, and cannot overcome rules that are enforced higher up. (Indeed, in general, doing so would be a bad thing; imagine an MPI code running four OpenMP processes on the same node and partitioning the logical CPUs to avoid interference; OpenMP ignoring that and running each process on all logical CPUs would over-subscribe the machine!)

Looking at [the cpuset man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/cpuset.7.html), we see

> Cpusets are integrated with the sched_setaffinity(2) scheduling
> affinity mechanism and the mbind(2) and set_mempolicy(2) memory-
> placement mechanisms in the kernel.  Neither of these mechanisms
> let a process make use of a CPU or memory node that is not
> allowed by that process's cpuset.  If changes to a process's
> cpuset placement conflict with these other mechanisms, then
> cpuset placement is enforced even if it means overriding these
> other mechanisms.

So it is explicitly saying that the cpuset implementation is designed to stop code from escaping, yet that is what you seem to want.

Therefore I think this has nothing much to do with OpenMP, which is merely obeying the rules of the Linux system on which it is running.

Comment: Note, though, that if you can use `sched_setaffinity(...)` to force thread placement inside the isolated group of logicalCPUs (as you seem to be saying), then setting `OMP_PROC_BIND` might be helpful. (See https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpse52.html ).